# If/else condition inside an Object

Tags: javascript

```
function Validator(formIsValid) {
    if(this.formIsValid) {
        alert('Form is valid!');
    }
    else {
        alert('Form is invalid...');
    } 
}
Validator.prototype = { // Notice the .prototype here, it's important!

  formIsValid: true, 

  enforceTextFieldMinLength: function(field, minLength) {
      if (!field.value || field.value.length < minLength) {
            this.formIsValid = false;
      }   
  },

  enforceLabelHasText: function(label) {
        if (!label.text) {
            this.formIsValid = false;
        }
  }
}
//var val = new Validator();
```

The above is my Val.js. This is how i am using in my otherFile.js

```
AddPatient.Firstname = FirstNameValue || Validator.enforceLabelHasText(FirstName);
```

I get an error saying `cannot find function enforceLabelHasText in Object function Validator(formIsValid)`

Comment: That's not a null pointer problem; it's simply a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put expressions in an object definition. If you want code to be executed after an object instance is created, you should use:

```
function Validator() {
    if(this.formIsValid) {
        alert('Form is valid!');
    }
    else {
        alert('Form is invalid...');
    } 
}
Validator.prototype = { // Notice the .prototype here, it's important!

  formIsValid: true, 

  enforceTextFieldMinLength: function(field, minLength) {
      if (!field.value || field.value.length < minLength) {
            this.formIsValid = false;
      }   
  },

  enforceLabelHasText: function(label) {
        if (!label.text) {
            this.formIsValid = false;
        }
  }
}
var a = new Validator();
```

This is a dummy solution; you will want to add arguments to the `Validator()` function, to initialize `formIsValid` and the other values. I suggest you should read [the MDC's description on prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Class-Based_vs._Prototype-Based_Languages).

**EDIT**: If you went with the prototype solution, you need to call `val.enforceLabelHasText(FirstName)`, after making `val` a global variable (either by omitting the `var` or by using `var window.val = new Validator()`).

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: It throws me Valdiator is undefined error when i include all this into an file.

Comment: @John Cooper that was a spelling error; I spelled `Valdiator` instead of `Validator`. It should be ok now.

Comment: @Gabi Is this the *only* way to create an object with code that runs as a constructor with an object literal?

Comment: You can write the code _after_ the object definition, like this: `var Validator = {...}; if(Validator.formIsValid) {...} `.

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: How would i call the enforce function from my other JS code... Note: All this Valdiator code is in Val.js

Comment: @John just like you did with the `.formIsValid`: `Validator.enforceLabelHasText(label)`. This will work if your `Validator` object is in the global scope.

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: I have updated my original post... i get an error cannot find function enforceLabelHasText in Object function Validator(formIsValid)

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: Val instance is made global, but when i press done button it does not check for val.enforceLabelHasText(FirstName), instead it checks on the load of the page itself.. whether the fields are empty or not...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The constructor would show an alert before it was possible to call any of the methods on the constructed object.

Answer (score 5):

This is not valid syntax.

You've dumped an `if/else` condition inside an object definition, like this:

```
var myObj = { a, b, c, d, 
  if (true) {
     alert('WTF!');
  }
};
```

Procedural code like this must be inside a function.

Answer (score 4):

You **can** insert logic into an object literal, using an [iife](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Like this;

```js
const testable = 1
const obj = {
  a: 'value1',
  b: (() => {
    if (testable === 1) {
      return 'testable was 1'
    } else {
      return 'testable was not 1'
    }
   })()
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: `const obj = { a: 'value1', b: checkTestable() }` would accomplish the same thing without an iife, but I don't think this is really what OP was going for (I don't think he really thought through what he was trying to do.)

Comment: Thanks. I converted this one to switch. Works well.

Answer (score 2):

`Validator` is an object literal and you can only assign properties there, not arbitrary code.

You could assign a function which includes your code to a property.

Answer (score 1):

Bind this to a variable in the beginning.

```
var that = this;
```

This keeps this changing and point to something else. 
And use firebug!